# Was there a tax advantage for ex-pats to stay out of the UK, even for brief visits?

Tags: united-kingdom, taxes

The question [Was there a British tax for British citizens staying abroad in the fifties](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/64271/was-there-a-british-tax-for-british-citizens-staying-abroad-in-the-fifties) reminded me of a plot point in the play-within-a-play in [Noises Off](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noises_Off). The play was written in the 1970's, and the play-within-the-play (*Nothing On*) appeared to be set even earlier.

Two of the characters of *Nothing On* are a British couple who are letting out their home while living abroad. In the play, they are visiting back home to retrieve paperwork that they had left behind. They are also trying to avoid Inland Revenue because they aren't supposed to be in the UK, and if they are discovered, there will be large tax consequences.

What sort of tax consequences would there be for ex-patriots *temporarily* returning to Britain in that era?

Comment: You're describing a *tax exile*: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tax_exile. They still exist in the UK and many countries.

Comment: UK taxation is based on "residence". Any British person, including anyone said to be "domiciled" in the UK,  who can show that they were non-resident in any tax year generally-speaking escapes income tax. But the position is not quite as simple as that, and anyone needing tax-planning advice should consult a professional.

Comment: It was certainly a trope of British fiction in the third quarter of the 20th century, the person who can't come back to the UK for tax reasons.